# Amazon Checkout - Pay User

Tags: payment-services, amazon-pay

I am looking at the different payment options from Amazon and have read various articles, discussing the differences and probably going to go with Amazon Checkout since I don't want user to leave my site and want a customizable checkout. However, does Amazon Checkout allow me to pay certain users from my site/account? I guess like PayPal's Adaptive Payments feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give more details on what your payment needs and why you want something else than Amazon. There are many alternatives but in order to give good answer you need to specify more details, type of goods, target market (US or global), withdrawals ticket price, etc..

Comment: Hi, I will be adding Paypal as well as Google Checkout, but will be starting off with Amazon. These are what I need:
1. my site basically provides services, and certain users will pay me, while I will have to pay other users. So it would have to support that. From what Amazon says, Amazon FPS is the ideal option for this. This is just US for now. 
2. However I also want the user to never leave my site when payment and I don't know if FPS allows that. 
3. Finally I want everything to be customizable so I can match the look & feel of my site. Thanks

Comment: FYI, FPS is a legacy product and will be going away "soon". next year I think. If you are going to use Amazon I would recommend Login and Pay with Amazon. It is their newest and most robust product.